# Having trouble cleaning out spaces in a string

Tags: c++, string, trim

Lets say I have three strings like that

```
"RES-003 :"
"RES 007 :"
" RES-015      :"
```

I want them to look like that when I show them

```
"RES-003:"
"RES 007:"
"RES-015:"
```

I was trying to solve that, however I can't get it right because when I try to clean up the spaces in between the colon and the numbers I delete the space in the second string "RES 007 :" so it changes it to "RES007:".

My trim function looks like that.

```
std::string& Reservation::trim(std::string& s) {
        bool valid = true;
        s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(' '));
        s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1);

        while (valid)
        {
            if (s.find("  ") != std::string::npos) {
                s.erase(s.find("  "), 1);
                valid = true;
                if (s.find(" ") != std::string::npos) {
                    s.erase(s.find(" "), 1);
                    valid = true;
                }
            }
            else
                valid = false;
        }

        return s;
    }
```

What can I do to improve it or I have to completely replace it?

Comment: If you know the format of the strings, i.e 3 characters hypen 3 digits space colon, then find the first non-space character, read the next 7 into a new string.

Comment: Trim spaces from the beginning and the end.  Trim all multi-spaces to a single space.  Trim space-colon to a colon.  Boom, done.

Comment: @Eljay That's nice idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption, based on the examples you provided, that the format of your string is:

`\s*[A-Z]{3}[\s\-][0-9]{3}\s*:\s*`

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto trimStr = [](const auto& str) -> std::string 
    {
        auto first = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), 
            [](unsigned char c){ return !std::isspace(c); });
        
        return std::string(first, first+7) + ":";
    };

    std::vector<std::string> examples = 
    { 
        "RES-003 :",
        "RES 007 :",
        " RES-015      :"
    };

    for(const auto& elem : examples)
    {
        std::cout << trimStr(elem) << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:27,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:27,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++auto+trimStr+%3D+%5B%5D(const+auto%26+str)+-%3E+std::string+%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++auto+first+%3D+std::find_if(str.begin(),+str.end(),+%0A++++++++++++%5B%5D(unsigned+char+c)%7B+return+!!std::isspace(c)%3B+%7D)%3B%0A++++++++%0A++++++++return+std::string(first,+first%2B7)+%2B+%22:%22%3B%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::string%3E+examples+%3D+%0A++++%7B+%0A++++++++%22RES-003+:%22,%0A++++++++%22RES+007+:%22,%0A++++++++%22+RES-015++++++:%22%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%0A++++for(const+auto%26+elem+:+examples)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+trimStr(elem)+%3C%3C+%22%5Cn%22%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:45.28727612542895,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%270%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.620151213375685,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+10.2%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:54.71272387457105,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: In production code, one should never assumes that the format is always right. Thus `first` and `first+7` should be validated (and possibly the content in between).

Comment: @Phil1970 I agree, definitely not production quality, just a simple example of trimming a string.